# HADR solutions for SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking for some HADR solutions for our organization. I know we should have Enterprise edition to have the full fledged features but what we have is Standard Edition of SQL Server. I'm new to this organisation and in my previous endeavours I have set up HADR solutions only in Enterprise edition.

While I researched I found we can have Basic AG with Standard edition but I cant have more than one DB in the AG which makes the HA plan disastrous for our applications. Transaction Replication is not allowed in standard edition.

Is there any simple HA Plan any of you have configured with standard edition? I'm looking for the best options I'm left with before proposing Enterprise edition. Please advise.

Comment: Mirroring is still at the individual database level so you won't want that. The only other thing for HA is an FCI, which does work in standard edition. Log shipping, et al, are not HA but rather DR solutions.

Comment: @SeanGallardy you can do some scripting to get LS/Mirrored databases to fail over in groups, but yeah...

Comment: Thank you @SeanGallardy. I think FCI is the pretty decent option I have!

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik Thank you for your comment :) Big follower of Brent Ozar Unlimited Blogs :)

Comment: @Ramya glad you like them! Thanks for reading!

Comment: @Ramya : Transnational Replication is available in SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition.I am using Transactional Replication to replicate data from Primary server to Secondary server.As Trnsactional Replication is not a HA solution i am thinking of using Log shipping once i fail over to the secondary server.Yet to implement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Log Shipping for DR.  Not so much HA as no automatic failover, but still better than nothing.   Use Windows cluster for HA, and Log ship them to somewhere else.

transactional replication IS allowed in standard:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-supported-features-for-sql-server-2016#a-namereplicationa-replication

But is not really an HADR solution